# Android Java POST data

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm pretty new to Android java. My code is working perfectly, all I can't figure out is how to send POST data to my PHP file so I can prepare the correct select query. All help will be appreciated thanks!

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    Integer result = 0;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        // 200 represents HTTP OK
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            parseResult(response.toString());
            result = 1; // Successful
        } else {
            result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need the `urlConnection`'s output stream for that

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit provides a simple but powerful mechanism to connect to the back-ends (servers in PHP or other languages where real data are stored).

First of all define your business interface.

```
public interface MyBiz {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/rest/api/path")
    void doMyBiz(@Body Map<String, String> map);
}
```

now create a new instance:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://dpq.co.ir")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
MyBiz service = retrofit.create(MyBiz.class);
```

and finally post data:

```
Map<String, Object> data;
...
doMyBiz(data);
```

For more infor

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library like OkHttp which not only makes what you are looking to do very easy, but you may want to later explore the features it offers such as caching and cookie management etc.

It's very easy to add it to your build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
}
```

And to make the POST call to your PHP page it only takes a few more lines. You use ".add('key', 'value')" to add additional post parameters:

```
RequestBody formBody = null;
formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("emailAddress", emailAddress)
        .add("token", token)
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.yourwebsite.com/your/api/endpoint")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
```

Then you're done. Make sure to put it inside an Async task like you already are.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HttpUrlConnection for making network calls, so you just have to set the method for connection 'POST'.

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

you have to decide how you are going to set the parameter, either you are going to send it in Json format or you want to send it in urlEncoded format

to send parameter in Json Format:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

or

to send it in urlEncoded format:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

set other properties and streaming mode(where 'params' are your parameter to send)

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.getBytes().length);
```

get the OutPutStream and write the bytes(of parameters which you want to send)

```
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(params);
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

After that you can further continue to check for response code and get the inputStream

```
if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
     ....
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is code from one of my project. Some methods are depriciated, but are still working.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(StaticMeth.webPageUrl + "saveToServer.php");
    String message;

    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Long.toString(mId)));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        String answer = StaticMeth.convertStreamToString(is);
        if(answer.equals("Successfully \n")){
            changeToSyncronized();
            message = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.successfully_saved);
        }else{
            message = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.saved_local_server_problems);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        message = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.saved_local_conn_problems);
    }
    return message;
}
```